# Google SSO not asking for scope for just one user (other users OK)

Tags: google-oauth, single-sign-on, gmail-api

I'm seeing a strange problem with google SSO and one of my users.

I'm requesting the following scopes using the oauth:

```
    const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline', // we want refresh tokens
      scope: ['email'],
      state: '{...}',  //state object
      prompt: 'consent', 
      hd: 'example.com', // restrict to just our domain
      include_granted_scopes: true,
    });
```

For every other user redirected to `url`, they are given a consent screen after authenticating that looks like this:

[image]

EXCEPT for one user. For this user - when they authenticate, there is no consent screen, and they are logged in with the bare minimum scope.

When the user looks at their account security page, they see our webapp as authorized with no scope. I've asked the user to revoke the app permissions and to try logging in again, but the same thing happens. They are logged in with no consent screen and no scope. Again, the strange thing is that it is only occurring for this one user.

Comment: Can you verify if that specific user is part of your organization? Can you ask the user to do it in incognito mode? If it still won't do, can you try and use `select_account` for the prompt and see if it shows on that user. If it shows, ask the user to re-select the account and see if the prompt shows afterwards. And if it still won't work, ask the user to select another account available to confirm if the prompt or an error won't even show. Sorry if i'm grasping at straws here, it is quite difficult for me to replicate your issue.

Comment: the user is part of our organization. We've tried incognito mode, signing out of chrome, etc. He does select his account, and it shows his user name. He chooses his username, enters a password, and the the login popup disappears, and an authenticated token is returned to the webapp. (just returned with no scope)

Comment: I tried replicating your issue on my end but to no avail. For now, what I can recommend is to file this bug in [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) and try to create another email for the user in the meantime while you wait for the appropriate fix/explanation since it only happens on that specific user. Creating another one might be your best solution for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit in this case was:

`include_granted_scopes: true,`

The other users for whom the consent screen was shown had at some time in the past been given the correct scope, and granted permission. Therefore, on any subsequent grant, the consent screen showed the previously granted scopes. The source code, at some point, changed and removed those particular scopes (and thus, we were only left with the `email` scope as shown in the question.

Interestingly, the `email` scope does not have to be consented to, and is automatic so it returned the user to our app with that granted scope, having never showed the consent screen to that one user.

Changing the scope to actually include the correct scopes now allows all users to see the consent screen and grant the proper scopes:

```
    const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline', // we want refresh tokens
      scope: ['email',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
             ],
      state: '{...}',  //state object
      prompt: 'consent', 
      hd: 'example.com', // restrict to just our domain
      include_granted_scopes: true,
    });
```